# Google app engine mail sends without error, but cannot be found in inbox

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am using google app engine's mail to send email. Bellow is my code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
try {
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(message);
Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new InvalidMailInputException("Invalid email.");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new InvalidMailInputException("Unable to send eamil at this time.");
    }
```

Log:

```
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO: MailService.send
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   From: myaddress@gmail.com
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   To: myaddress@gmail.com
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Reply-to: myaddress@gmail.com
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Subject: Appoint has been cancelled successfully (5)
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:   Body:
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Content-type: text/plain
Apr 13, 2013 5:26:29 PM com.google.appengine.api.mail.dev.LocalMailService log
INFO:     Data length: 147
```

In the log message I have not recived any errors. However, I am not receiving email as well.

Appriceate your help.

Comment: have you checked your spam folder ;-)

Comment: @TimHoffman yea I thoroughly checked it. No luck ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the local development server.  In such case no mail is actually sent.

From:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Development_Server

> When an application running in the development server calls the Mail service to send an email message, the message is printed to the log. The Java development server does not send the email message.

Comment: Pleasure, there are a few similar "gotchas" with xmpp message sending on dev server etc.  However most times log has some indication. Although only partly related to your question you might try some mail services like Postmark, Mandrill... They work fine with app engine (live and dev) and usually have some free tier.